# Can brawler fighters sustain grabs from their powers?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, fighter, grapple

The brawler fighter attack powers that enable grabbing contain the following line:

> ... The grab ends automatically at the end of your next turn.

Can players sustain these grabs with a minor action on their next turn to sustain the grab?

> **Sustaining a Grab**: You sustain a grab as a minor action. You can end a grab as a free action

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they can't. This is because you didn't use an action that allows you to sustain the grab.

The text you've quoted pertaining to sustaining a grab appears to be from the 'Grab' section on page 290 of the Player's Handbook.

That section talks about a specific action called 'Grab' that results in a grab. If you use that action, you can sustain it in such a manner. The brawler didn't use that action, he used one of his powers. That power doesn't have a sustain line, it just ends the grab automatically.

I believe the confusion rises from the PH's use of the indefinite article: "a grab", which makes it seem like this rule applies to *all* grabs, rather than to just the grabs produced by this action.

This is made clearer in the Rules Compendium on page 243, where 'Grab' is rewritten to explicitly be a power with a sustain line:

> **Sustain Minor:** The grab persists until the end of your next turn.

Notice the use of the definite article: "the grab". This is referring specifically to the grab resulting from using the power 'Grab', not grabs in general.

Answer (score 1):

No, the grab ends.

To sustain the grab, it must still be active, but those powers force an end on the grab.

Comment: Sounds resonable, but are there any rules to back this statement up?

Comment: I agree with this answer. It's in the wording "the grab ends AUTOMATICALLY" To me, automatic suggests that you have no control over it. It's like the power is consciously deciding to end so It will end of it's own volition no matter what you do.

Comment: Doesn't that severely weaken the brawler fighter build? They get feats that allow them to do damage for sustaining a grab or do damage when an enemy fails to escape from a grab.

Comment: No, Brawlers are obscene. Because they can grab as part of an opportunity attack, on top of Combat Superiority blocking shifts. If the grabs don't auto-end, consider this: foe is hit for normal damage, grabbed. If they escape, they get hit for shifting and lost the move anyways.
The powers end automatically just to prevent a brawler being a 1H-fighter while at the same time pinning someone down (really well) via sustained grab.